# Angular force an undesired exclamation mark in url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, iis

When I click on this : `<a href="#/home">home</a>` the url is `localhost/Sites/App/#!/#%2Fhome`

When I click on this : `<a href="#!/home">home</a>` the url is `localhost/Sites/App/#!/home`

But this only works on my computer, for my co-workers it's the opposite, the links don't works if there are `!` in the url.

I understand the SEO best practices but we don't have a public website, we need to have a website working without exclamation mark in url.

I understand the `/` in the url are encoded because angular think this is not a path separator but why in my only computer ? We have the same code.

We use IIS or IIS express, Chrome or IE, there are no differences. When it works for me, it does not work for all of the others.

In the browser networks calls we can see there are no server calls between the click on the link and the bad url generation.

This is the module configuration :

```
angular.module('paper.app', [ 'ngMaterial'
                        , 'ngMessages'
                        , 'ngRoute'
                        , ...])
   .config(function ($routeProvider, $mdThemingProvider, $mdIconProvider, $locationProvider, $mdDateLocaleProvider, contentUrl, contentSvg) {

       $routeProvider
           .when("/", {
               templateUrl: contentUrl + 'view-home/html/home.html',
               controller: 'HomeController',
               controllerAs: 'homeCtrl'
           })
           .otherwise({
               redirectTo: '/'
           });

       $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

       ...
   });
```

This is the bower.json :

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "authors": [
        "..."
    ],
    "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ],
    "description": "",
    "main": "",
    "homepage": "",
    "dependencies": {
        "angular": "^1.5.7",
        "angular-material": "^1.0.9",
        "angular-route": "^1.5.7",
        "angular-material-data-table": "^0.10.9",
        "moment": "^2.14.1"
      }
}
```

Comment: Have you set in base url ?

Comment: Yes : `localhost/Sites/App/` in the `meta` of my page.

Comment: I have same issue, have you ever found solution for this ? 
I asked question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211755/i-have-weird-in-angularjs-route-and-all-other-routes-dont-work

Comment: See my answer related to your question [hier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41551864/3853300)!

Comment: See my answer related to your question [hier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41551864/3853300)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL hash-bang (#!/) prefix instead of simple hash (#/) in Angular 1.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash-in-angular-1-6)

Comment: @Mistalis How can it be a duplicate when it was asked first

Answer (score 32):

I solved it by adding this:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

Answer (score 4):

//Client side Configuration to pretty url
//Remove # from url

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and add this to your index.html 
`<base href="/"></base>`

Comment: I dont want to activate html5Mode, I need to keep the `#`