# Angular partials not working

Tags: angularjs, partials

I never had this problem before and I know this is a tiny issue... but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong... 1 of my partials is not loading correctly and instead it hits the otherwise route back to my /login (which I have assigned). 
Every time I click on the Create a survey link it redirects me back to the login and the URL displays this http://localhost:3000/#!/login#%2Fcreate but when I put http://localhost:3000/#!/create in the URL it works. Not quite sure what the problem is. Please HELP!

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
 $routeProvider
 .when('/login', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
  controller: 'UserController'
 })
 .when('/dashboard', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
  controller: 'SurveyController'
 })
 .when('/create', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/create.html',
  controller: 'SurveyController'
 })
 .when('/poll/:id', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/poll.html'
 })
 .otherwise({
  redirectTo: '/login'
 });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Survey Polls</title>
 <!-- CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"> 
 <!-- Angular -->
 <script src="angular/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
 <!-- jQuery/Bootstrap -->
 <script src="jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <!-- App.js -->
 <script src="app.js"></script>
 <!-- Controllers/Factories -->
 <script src="controllers/SurveyController.js"></script> 
 <script src="controllers/UserController.js"></script>
 <script src="factories/SurveyFactory.js"></script>
 <script src="factories/UserFactory.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
 <div class="container">
  <div ng-view></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>




<a href="#/create">Create a new survey</a>

<h3>Current polls:</h3>

<table border="1">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Survey Question</th>
   <th>Date Posted</th>
   <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="s in surveys">
   <td>{{ s._user.username }}</td>
   <td>{{ s.question }}</td>
   <td>{{ s.created_at }}</td>
   <td><button ng-show="loggedInUser._id == s._user._id" ng-click="delete(s._id)">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Which one is not working create?

Comment: Yes, sorry I edited my post for that. whoops!

Comment: show us how you are navigating to create state... the function which triggers it.

Comment: @Thalaivar its when I click on the "Create a new survey" a link

Comment: Have you tried using ng-href instead of just href?

Comment: remove the # from href and it works

Comment: @Mickers yes, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban I've tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: can you create a plunker? I've tried half of the code and it seems working, by the way is having SurveyController for both create and dashboard intentional?

Comment: I fixed it by adding a "!" in my href to be... "#!/create" but why does my URL have a ! in it? @YaserAdelMehraban

Comment: Is `http://localhost:3000/#/login` not working ? You don;t need the `!` mark here.

Comment: @bhantol I'm not sure where the "!" came from.

Comment: @bhantol the "!" is always there throughout my whole app and I do not know where it comes from.

Comment: I am suspecting you have some libbaries mixed up. Move jQuery and bootstrap above angularjs in index.html and also verify what is the version of the angular-route ?

Comment: By doing locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); things whould not have ! character. My guess is you are using some very old version of angularjs or route

Comment: "angular-route": "^1.6.0", @bhantol

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ng-href instead of just href.

Comment: so would it be <a ng-href="#/create">Create a new survey</a>

Comment: I have creat a plunker for you just a simple one and the link works fine please ahve a look   https://plnkr.co/edit/q4Bamm2was76KeBknkC7?p=preview

Comment: It works when I change the a href to "#!/create" but why does my URL have the "!" in it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38455077/angular-force-an-undesired-exclamation-mark-in-url). Add this line to your config to get rid of the exclamation point (!):

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

Comment: Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Glad that helped.