# AngularJS ui-router application has /#!/ in the URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an application with **ui.router** working normally, but another application the url has an **"!"** after **"#"**

Ex: `http://localhost:8090/dev/#!/home`

Why it happens?

The normal should be: `http://localhost:8090/dev/#/home`

Comment: How did you end up with "#!"?

Comment: Look at this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38455077/angular-force-an-undesired-exclamation-mark-in-url

Comment: I not put the "!". It is being placed automatically by the angular. If i remove in the url the angular place it there again, i want remove it.

Comment: It's a change in Angular 1.6 https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#location-due-to

Comment: @ErazerBrecht Thanks Mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this happens because `hashprefix` is not set.

```
$locationProvider
  .hashPrefix('!');
```

I guess you can set it to empty string and that is why you don't see `!`.

Alternatively you can enable html5mode`that will get rid of`hashbang` completely. Some older browsers don't support it, but generally not an issue, unless you need to support IE9 or something.

You can read about it e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting) or [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag).

Long story short if you configure `html5mode` properly, then you won't have the `hashbang` that is required for routing in older browsers that do not support it.