# AngularJS: How to remove #!/ (bang prefix) from URL?

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-1.6

I already have done `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` but it is not working. Whenever I access `http://example.com` it goes to `http://example.com/#!/`. Code is given here:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to EXTRANET home page
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
    .state('listrole', {
    url: "/list-role",
    views: {
      'main-content': {
        templateUrl: rootUrl+ 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'rolesCtrl'
      }
    }
    })
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

**Update**
I added `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');` as well but no difference. Also let me tell you that I am enter address in address bar and hitting enter. Am I doing right? how will browser find that it does not need to refresh from server?

**Update #2**

Ideally I want URL as `http://example.com` and `http://example.com/#!/list-role` to `http://example.com/list-role`. Right now `http://example.com/list-role` gives 404

**Update #3**

I am using nginx proxy, if that helps.

**Update #4**

Erased Cache. Now I can see `http://example.com` instead of `http://example.com/#!` but still `http://example.com/list-role` gives 404

Comment: put $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to remove this prefix, add this code to your config:

```
appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

[Source here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8) for more information.

---

### Update

If you want to remove the whole prefix (`#` and not only `!`), you may try [this solution](https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag):

**1) Activate the HTML5 mode and remove the prefix `!` in your module config**

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

**2) And then set base to `/` in the `<head>` on your index.html**

```
<head>
    ...
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

Comment: On refresh it is not working.. I am getting 404 on refresh,

Comment: The way you said to remove the whole prefix (# and not only !) didn't work with me

Comment: You saved me so much heartache with this! thank you

Answer (score 3):

Add to your html file `<head> <base href="/foldername/"> </head>`

and this one is for your app.js `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

this is for `.htaccess` create file if you don't have.

```
RewriteEngine On 
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d  
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ /foldername/
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will remove exclamatory (!) mark in URL

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

or else go to [Routing issue with AngularJS project using yeoman setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140716/routing-issue-with-angularjs-project-using-yeoman-setup/41142588#41142588)

it worked for me

Comment: It's not working. As soon as I hit F5 for refresh to root URl, it appendsin it

Comment: Add it app.js file and add dependency @Volatil3

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to app.js

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {

  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in .NET stack with MVC with AngularJS, this is what you have to do to remove the '#' from url:

1.Set up your base href in your _Layout page:

```
 <head> <base href="/"> </head>
```

2.Then, add following in your angular app config :

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
$locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

Please check this question: [AngularJS ui-router application has /#!/ in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365887/angularjs-ui-router-application-has-in-the-url)

Comment: No need to use symbol (!) in the brackets @Tome

Comment: @Shiva true. However is duplicate.

Comment: @Volatil3 $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); add this code and am unable to see in your code.

Comment: page not found issue

Comment: @Volatil3 can you please create a JSFiddle with your code.