# Unable to remove # from URL in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a simple single-page application in AngularJS. The URL appears something like this `.../Angular/index.html` and when I click on the link in the page it goes transforms to `.../Angular/index.html#/addStudent`.

Now, I wanted to remove the `#` from the URL, but I'm unable to do it. I googled it and found many answers, but none worked (I'm really new to Angular and programming), so it might be that I'm missing something really silly.

**Here's the code:**

```html
<html>
   
   <head>
      <title>Angular JS Views</title>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>
      <div ng-app = "mainApp">
         <p><a href = "#addStudent">Add Student</a></p>
         <p><a href = "#viewStudents">View Students</a></p>
         <div ng-view></div>
         
         <script type = "text/ng-template" id = "addStudent.htm">
            <h2> Add Student </h2>
            {{message}}
         </script>
         
         <script type = "text/ng-template" id = "viewStudents.htm">
            <h2> View Students </h2>
            {{message}}
         </script>
      </div>
      
      <script>
         var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);
         mainApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
            
            when('/addStudent', {
      //url:'/',
               templateUrl: 'addStudent.htm',
               controller: 'AddStudentController'
            }).
            
            when('/viewStudents', {
      //url:'/',
               templateUrl: 'viewStudents.htm',
               controller: 'ViewStudentsController'
            }).
            
            otherwise({
               redirectTo: '/addStudent'
            });
   //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
   //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
   //check browser support
       // if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
            //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); will cause an error $location in HTML5 mode requires a  tag to be present! Unless you set baseUrl tag after head tag like so: <head> <base href="/">

         // to know more about setting base URL visit: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

         // if you don't wish to set base URL then use this
        // $locationProvider.html5Mode({
          //       enabled: true,
            //     requireBase: false
    // rewriteLinks: true
    //      });
     //   }
            
         }]);
         
         mainApp.controller('AddStudentController', function($scope) {
            $scope.message = "This page will be used to display add student form";
         });
         
         mainApp.controller('ViewStudentsController', function($scope) {
            $scope.message = "This page will be used to display all the students";
         });
   
      </script>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the hash # from the angularjs ng-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629774/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-the-angularjs-ng-route)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing the fragment identifier from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-fragment-identifier-from-angularjs-urls-symbol)

Comment: @Ted Hi, I understand it's a duplicate but I wasn't able to solve the problem even after going through the given solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set HTML5-mode to true:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

And in your links, don't include the `#`. Do it like this instead:

```
<a href="/addStudent">Add Student</a>
```

Comment: My initial url was file:///C:/Users/.../Desktop/.../Angular/index.html and it was working with the # (url became something like file:///C:/Users/.../Desktop/.../Angular/index.html#/Addstudent). I tried using $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); as you can see the commented code(Also added $locationProvider in config and function both, As suggested in many answers of similar questions but none worked)

Comment: @RamnarayanChaudhary What's happening if you make the changes I suggested?

Comment: It removed the # from the url but unable to connect to the template. So it's showing error "file not found".

Comment: I tried the methods which are commented in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });
```

in your js and

```
<base href="http://localhost:4000" || "or your URL in here">
```

in main HTML

dont forget to `$locationProvider` in your config.

Comment: I tried using that but it wasn't working. It removed the # from the url but unable to connect to the template. So it's showing error "file not found" Could you please try this code in your system with changes, if this works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have made some changes please check

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the prefix (`#`), you can do the following:

#### 1) Activate the HTML5 mode in your module config

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

#### 2) Set base to `/` in the `<head`> on your index.html

```
<head>
    ...
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

---

Note that if you are using Angular 1.6, you will need to remove the `!` as well. You can see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461312/4927984).

Comment: I tried this. The url is as I expected(without #) but page is showing error 404.