# Remove # hashtag from angular 1.5 url

Tags: angularjs, spring-4

I am trying to remove the hashtags from my Angularjs app's URLs using the locationProvider, and it works well until I refresh a page manually. When I am refreshing page my angularjs js and css file now loading.
Please help me on that.

In index.jsp

App.js

myapp.config(function($routeProvider, USER_ROLES, IdleProvider, KeepaliveProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 }

urlrewrite.xml

### /login resources/partials/login.html   /login/brandname resources/partials/login.html   /home resources/partials/home.html

web.xml:

### http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0"> Archetype Created Web Application  UrlRewriteFilter org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter  confPath /WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml    UrlRewriteFilter /* REQUEST FORWARD

Comment: Hi All , please help me out on above issue.

Comment: You have to add base tag with base url in your index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing the fragment identifier from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-fragment-identifier-from-angularjs-urls-symbol)

Comment: Hi Kadir , thanks for reply. I have added like below 
  <base href="/Freekwent/" /> but getting same issue

Comment: @Protozoid , I am following same mentioned url but when I am refreshing page it is not loading my angular js file and css.

Answer (score 0):

adding base base tag could also help you solve the `#` problem. And also did you checked this link? https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Comment: Hi Janno Tabamo , I have checked above link also.I have done same. But when I am refreshing page my css and js file not loading.

Comment: are you using `nginx` in your backend? or its just pure frontend? you might find some help try check this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460772/angularjs-how-to-remove-bang-prefix-from-url

Comment: I am using spring in back-end for rest api and front-end angularjs. I have checked above url also.
Please help me out

Comment: Im not really familiar with spring. But I hope this link could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837715/spring-boot-with-angularjs-html5mode

Comment: This is a problem with the routing configuration of your backend.

Comment: Any one know what configuration I need to put on back-end side for routing because I am getting 404.